# expr displaying the expression rather than solving it

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here is my shell script,

```
#! /bin/sh
# basic calculator
echo "Please input your choice"
printf " 1.Addition \n 2.SUbstraction \n 3.Multiplication \n 4.Division\n"
read choice
case "$choice" in
    1) echo "Enter number 1:";read n1;echo "Enter number 2:";read n2;t=$(expr "$n1"+"$n2");echo "$n1+$n2=$t";;
    2) echo "Enter number 1:";read n1;echo "Enter number 2:";read n2;t='expr $n1-$n2';echo "$n1-$n2=$t";;       
    3) echo "Enter number 1:";read n1;echo "Enter number 2:";read n2;t='expr $n1\*$n2';echo "$n1*$n2=$t";;
    4) echo "Enter number 1:";read n1;echo "Enter number 2:";read n2;t='expr $n1/$n2';echo "$n1/$n2=$t";;
esac
```

Here is my output,

```
Script started on Sunday 08 November 2015 12:05:21 PM IST
Please input your choice
 1.Addition 
 2.SUbstraction 
 3.Multiplication 
 4.Division
1
Enter number 1:
5
Enter number 2:
6
5+6=5+6
```

The problem is that my expr isnt actually solving the expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some versions of `expr` it's recommended to use shell arithmetic instead:

```
$ echo $((5+6))
11
$ echo $((5>=6))
0
```

Using shell arithmetic using spaces to separate ints is not necessary if desired.

> The expr utility makes no lexical distinction between arguments which
>   may
>        be operators and arguments which may be operands.  An operand which is
>        lexically identical to an operator will be considered a syntax error.
>
> ```
>  The syntax of the expr command in general is historic and inconvenient.
>  New applications are advised to use shell arithmetic rather than expr
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Whitespace matters:

```
$ expr 5+6
5+6
$ expr 5 + 6       
11
```

To do arithmetic, you need to give `expr` 3 distinct arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quotes (`'`) instead of backticks ( ` ) for the other calls to `expr`. But as I'L'l points out, there's almost never any reason to use `expr` to perform arithmetic.